# Using google calendar API

Tags: vbscript, calendar, google-calendar-api

I need to add/edit/del events to a shared Google cal using visual basic or Access (not using VB.NET) to post events from a custom desktop calendar built in Access and some VB.  My goal - users can have an internal office calendar used for years and fully integrated with office functions, while choosing to share some of these events on a Web calendar for scheduling.

I can find others not using VB.NET who want to do the same, but none of their posts have been successful in finding out how.

If I cannot use the google API with VB (not vb.net) can I use vbscript to add/del calendar events?  I found some sample code that was successful for adding an event with vbscript, but no successful code in vbscript to del or edit (tho others have tried).

Appreciate any help/suggestions on  this.  After hours across 2 days searching, this group looks like my final hope.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I suggest adding the source (or working example) of adding events. The next person may be able to produce a working variation based on the code, and it would certainly save them the trouble of trying to find them.